# reading plist file crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, read-write

read in did load:

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]; //5

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
}

//load in text fields.
NSMutableDictionary *savedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

nameField.text = [[savedData objectForKey:@"name"] stringValue];
locationTextField.text = [[savedData objectForKey:@"location"] stringValue];
sectorTextField.text = [[savedData objectForKey:@"sector"] stringValue];
```

Write on button click:

```
    - (IBAction)writingButton:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    //[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];
    [data setObject:[NSString stringWithString:nameField.text] forKey:@"name"];
    [data setObject:[NSString stringWithString:locationTextField.text] forKey:@"location"];
    [data setObject:[NSString stringWithString:sectorTextField.text] forKey:@"sector"];
}
```

the plist file:

[image]

The error:

> 2012-09-04 17:03:40.360 app[4849:c07] -[__NSCFString stringValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aa38f0 2012-09-04
>   17:03:40.362 app[4849:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString
>   stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aa38f0'

Any ideas? cheers.

Comment: And also, please read the error message. It's in plain, comprehensible English.

Comment: I didn't know id I needed a different selector (I've been working with ios apps outside of cocos2d for about a month an half now so i'm still learning)

Comment: the value in plist are already of type String, then why do you want to typecast them using [[savedData objectForKey:@"name"]stringValue]. Just use [[savedData objectForKey:@"name"] and so on.

Comment: @dev6546 I see :) But still, in NSDictionary's documentation, it's clearly stated how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary stores NSString objects directly - there's no need to call a (nonexistent) method called `- stringValue`. Simply write

```
nameField.text = [savedData objectForKey:@"name"];
```

and so on.

(Why do you think this method call would have been necessary?)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, could you see why the code inside my button click wouldnt work? Reading is working fine now, but writing isnt, I've tried also moving the code to didClose but I'm not having any joy with that either.

Comment: @dev6546 what do you mean by "write is not working"? Aren't the values in the NSMutableDictionary set?

Comment: All three are uiTextFields two are set in: -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerview didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component and the final is just setup with a keyboard. When I close and open the app they're not saved though. It loads the ones from the plist file in my resources folder.

Comment: @dev6546 of course they aren't. You're not writing out the contents of the dictionary. Setting the values of the in-memory instance of a dictionary obviously doesn't change the values in the file itself. Furthermore, you can't updated/write files in your app bundle (it's readonly for security reasons) - you have to store your plist file in the Documents or Library directory and then use NSDictionary's `writeToFile:atomically:` method to actually save the changes.